# Linq Order By 2 fields in on condition

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of Customers with a CustomerID and a ParentCustomerID that refers to another Customer's CustomerID

What I want is to order my list of Customers by the ParentCustomerID or CustomerID if the ParentCustomerID is 0, the idea being that I want to list all my customer, but "group" them in a way to have the parent with it's children.

The result would look like this

```
Customer 1 - Parent 0
Customer 2 - Parent 1
Customer 3 - Parent 1
Customer 4 - Parent 0
Customer 5 - Parent 0
Customer 6 - Parent 5
```

How can I write my Linq query to achieve that ?

Comment: Can you give the expected *results* for your sample data?

Comment: As I understand, you have one field that named as `ParentCustomerID`. You want to list by `CustomerID`. Every CustomerID could have some ParentCustomerIDs right? So you can try to create 2 linq query. First one gets the CustomerIDs and second one checks if the CustomerID has ParentCustomerIDs.

Comment: That is a devilishly hard ordering requirement - are you sure you're not really trying to group for real? It would be much easier

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whew, after a bit of head-scratching, this appears to do exactly what you're after

```
var ordered = customers.OrderBy(c => c.ParentCustomerId == 0 ? c.CustomerId : c.ParentCustomerId)
                       .ThenBy(c => c.CustomerId);
```

Live example: http://rextester.com/OKKXW89193

Comment: You beat me to it! We had a very similar requirement once, except that ParentCustomerId was a null `int?` instead of zero. Same solution though, `customers.OrderBy(c => c.ParentCustomerId.HasValue ? c.CustomerId : c.ParentCustomerId.Value)
                       .ThenBy(c => c.CustomerId);`

Comment: That's the same as I have done before. It's not hard at all. Sorry to be honest here :)

This should work fine.

Comment: Thanks. I already had tried the first .orderBy clause you have, but it was not giving me the result I wanted. I guess it's the .thenBy that I was missing.

Answer (score 0):

Updated accordingly. From what you have described on your question, this should be enough.

Give it a try and post results, please:

```
var ordered = customers
   .Select(_c => new { Factor1 = _c.ParentCustomerID == 0 ? _c.CustomerID : _c.ParentCustomerID, Factor2 = _c.CustomerID, Customer = _c })
   .OrderBy(_customer => _customer.Factor1)
   .ThenBy(_customer => _customer.Factor2)
   .Select(_c => _c.Customer);
```

Comment: This will not do as the OP asked - it will put all customers with `0` parent first, then order by `Id`

Answer (score 0):

You can write a LINQ query that is close to your verbal description. First order parents and children together based on the parents' id, then order children based on their id after their respective parents.

```
customers.OrderBy(c => c.ParentID > 0 ? c.ParentID : c.CustomerID)
         .ThenBy(c => c.ParentID == 0 ? 0 : c.CustomerID)
```

This assumes that your hierarchy is only one level deep (i.e. a customer who is a parent cannot also be a child). I don't believe that a recursive operation can be expressed in LINQ.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an idea, as you can see in OP's example, the hidden order values are like this:

```
Customer 1 - Parent 0 -- OrderValue is 1.0
Customer 2 - Parent 1 -- OrderValue is 1.2
Customer 3 - Parent 1 -- OrderValue is 1.3
Customer 4 - Parent 0 -- OrderValue is 4.0
Customer 5 - Parent 0 -- OrderValue is 5.0
Customer 6 - Parent 5 -- OrderValue is 5.6
```

so here is my code:

```
            var ordered =
            customers.OrderBy(
                c =>
                    c.ParentCustomerId == 0
                        ? c.CustomerId.ToString() + "." + c.ParentCustomerId.ToString());
                        : c.ParentCustomerId.ToString() + "." + c.CustomerId.ToString());
```

or if you don't like string:

```
            var ordered = customers.OrderBy(
            c => 
                c.ParentCustomerId ==0
                ? c.CustomerId
                : c.ParentCustomerId + c.CustomerId / (double)customers.Count);
```

Comment: I tried some of the other codes, if you change to {Customer 2 - Parent 4}, they do not work correctly

Comment: whoever downvoted care to explain why? And OP stated " ...group them in a way to have the parent with it's children". The answer OP picked does not work that way: if you change the Customer2 to have ParentCustomerID 4. The children is listed before parent.

Answer (score -1):

```
    var ordered = customers.OrderBy(_customer => customer.CustomerID)
                           .ThenBy(_customer => _customer.CustomerParentID);
```

Should work.